# IF function only working if Value is TRUE and remitting a #NA if the Value is FALSE on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

Can anyone help me with the following formula? Basically it works when the condition is TRUE but gives me an error when the condition is FALSE. I would like the cell to remit the value "0" if the condition is FALSE:

```
=IF((VLOOKUP(A31,D16:D22,1,0)), (SUM((EOMONTH(A31,0))-(EOMONTH(A31,-1)+1))*(B7/30)), "0")
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the vlookup in an iserror() function. Also, since 0 is numerical, you don't need quotes around it.

Edit: should be "not iserror ()" based on your statement, sorry.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer Audra..

Answer (score 0):

Your formula takes the number of days in the month A31 and subtracts 1 and then multiplies by B7 and divides by 30 - is that right, that will use 29 for a November date or 30 for December, is that the intention? If so you can do that more simply like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(D16:D22,A31),(DAY(EOMONTH(A31,0))-1)*B7/30,0)`